# number_to_currency rounding precision wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I am very curious why Ruby render decimal with precision 2 inconsistently.

For example:

```
helper.number_to_currency 9.995
```

=> "$9.99"

whilst

```
helper.number_to_currency 10.995
```

=> "$11.00"...should it be "$10.99"?

Comment: This may be a floating point precision issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a floating point precision error. I will probably submit a patch to fix this because I'm using number_to_currency on my website too.

Here's what's happening in more detail:

`number_to_currency` ends up just calling `number_with_precision` to get the number correctly formatted.  `number_with_precision` immediately converts the number to a Float.  Essentially, it comes down to this line in the Rails code:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb, line 280
rounded_number = BigDecimal.new((number * (10 ** precision)).to_s).round.to_f / 10 ** precision
```

The number you provide is multiplied by 100 before it is converted to BigDecimal.  Look at this simple irb session:

```
irb(main):001:0> 9.995 * 100
=> 999.4999999999999
```

That number would obviously round down to 999, then it will be divided by 100 to give you 9.99.

The only workaround for this that I can think of for the moment is to do your own rounding before you pass in the number.

Comment: I submitted a patch that you can watch here:
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6182-another-rounding-problem-in-number_with_precision

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it is using "Round half to odd" rule.

So "1.5" gets rounded down to the nearest odd number (1) and 2.5 gets rounded up to the nearest odd number (3).

For a randomly distributed set of numbers to be rounded this form of rounding will consitently produce the smallest difference between the sum of unrounded numbers and the sum of rounded numbers.